# Editing UITableView programmatically show delete button on ALL rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know that I can swipe to show the red Minus button on a row which then lets me tap it to show the right side Delete button. I also know that I can set the `UITableView` into editing mode which will show the red minus button on the left which I can then tap to show the Delete button.

However, I would like to show the Delete button on EVERY row when I put the `UITableView` into editing mode. I can't find a way to do that and web searches are filled with results about the common topics dealing with deleting one row instead of showing the Delete buttons on all rows.

How do I programmatically show the right-hand side Delete button on EVERY row in a `UITableView`? Not the red Minus button on the left side.

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing, and so far I've only found answers saying it needs to be done using custom scrollview implementations on the cells.

Answer (score -3):

[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];

Comment: The first paragraph of my post explains that I already know that. You didn't properly read the post.